# Return Non Null Cookies And Count

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two worksheets in my workbook.  The first worksheet is titled SalesPerson and should show a rundown of the salesman that is entered in cell B1 and the type & quantity of cookies sold.  Layout is like so:
Name: George

Cookies Sold:  Quantity:
I then have a second worksheet called Sales Data that shows each sales person and the type of cookies and the number that the individual sold.  Layout is like so

```
.......Choc Chip....Vanilla....Lemon....etc
George  4            12          0
Bob                   3
Jerry                 4          1
```

So let's say for example in cell B1 the name George was entered, under the headers Cookies Sold and Quantity (which begin in A3 & B3) I would want to return the below

```
Choc Chip     4
Vanilla       12
```

Is there an excel formula that can do this?  I could use `VLOOKUP` or a combined method of `Index(Match())`if SalesPerson contained all possible cookies and just look up the count sold, but since it does not what option do I have to return **BOTH** the cookies and the count where the count >= 1 to my SalesPerson worksheet?

I have thought about using a `PIVOT TABLE` but this just helps drill down on the data, not return the data to my SalesPerson worksheet, and I also have looked at using the `VLOOKUP()` function, but I could only get this to return one value not both the pie type and the count.

**EDIT**
I could use `=INDEX(A1:D6, 4, 3)` to return the count but how could I in the same swoop return the pie?

I know that `INDEX()MATCH()MATCH()` works when you have both the veritical and horizontal lookup values, but could this be transposed to return the horizontal value as well as the return value?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was the result? Have you looked at using a pivot table?

Comment: @CharlieRB -- see my edit.  Yes I have tried a pivot table as well as using the VLOOKUP() but to no success.

Comment: Can you get your Index formula to return the pie separately?

Comment: @BruceWayne - that would work as long as I can ensure that only pies with a >= 1 count are returned AND the pie is lined up with the correct count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets get the list of cookies.  We need to use an array formula.  My go to formula in this case is AGGREGATE() inside an INDEX.  I put "George" in A8 with the data in A1:D4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$D$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($B$2:$D$4)-1)/(($A$2:$A$4=$A$8)*($B$2:$D$4<>0)*($B$2:$D$4<>"")),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Then copied that formula down enough rows to cover all possible list lengths.

Then I used a standard INDEX/MATCH/MATCH to find the numbers:

```
=IF(A9<>"",INDEX($A:$D,MATCH($A$8,$A:$A,0),MATCH($A9,$1:$1,0)),"")
```

And again copied that down the same number of rows.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly!  What is the 15,6 mean inside the aggregate?

Comment: AGGREGATE is an aggregate of many formulas, the first number `15` is for SMALL().  The `6` tells it to skip any errors, which we want because by dividing by a set of Boolean,  we are forcing a #DIV0 error for those values we do not want. @user2676140